# Android: unable to parse the package in galaxy tab

Tags: android, apk, galaxy-tab

I have made a sample application and installed it in Galaxy tab.When i open the application it says "There is a problem parsing the package" and i cannot see any errors.I can run the apk in the emulator and it works fine.I have searched it forums but i didn't find the answers relevant.Please suggest me a solution to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you compiled a package with the same package name as one already installed on the phone.

That, or you haven't signed the package properly with a key.

Do either of those sound possible?

Comment: Do i need to change the package name and build it again?

Comment: Yes! Say it is com.google.android.alarmclock and the alarm clock app with that name is already installed, you would get the error you described. Rename it to something about you... org.myorganization.alarmclock You will have to change that in the Manifest.xml and the actual package in Eclipse.

Comment: how did you transfer the package to the galaxy? I had have the same problem, I uploaded the apk to a webserver and downloaded it via Browser, but i performed the upload in ASCII mode not binary and this causes the problem

Comment: i have exported the apk file from another system and installed it in Galaxy.it worked fine.I got to know that when i updated the android version 14 it gave me an error in moving a folder which stopped the update. this may be a problem.Whatever apk file i generated in my system doesn't work in phone.

Comment: And you used the same key to sign it? Did you change the package name?

Comment: No i haven't changed the packaged name and used the same key to sign it.It worked even if i use the Apk in the bin folder of the application to install it in Galaxy tab.

Comment: The apk in the bin folder is unsigned, I believe. Make sure to completely remove the app installed on the phone. Then install it again, from the computer in question, compile sign and package the apk and then install it...should work.

Answer (score 1):

This because your app is not compatible with your device. It might you set the minSDKVersion value to high and If your device API level is lower then minSDKVersion then it gives parsing package error or you set the maxSDKVersion to lower than your device API level.

For ex : If your device is Android 2.2 then you made the APK set the minSDKVersion to 10 then it wont work in the Android 2.2 and will give the parsing package error or If you set the maxSDKVersion to 8 then app won't install above Android OS 2.2 and if you try to install then you will get the Parsing package error.